# Determine when drawing of Geojson is complete in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, listener, geojson

Is there an event that gets fired when drawing of all features have completed when using the `loadGeoJson()` method in Google Maps API?

I read that you can listen for "idle" state of the map, but it seems like the map is considered idle when the load is complete, but before features are drawn.
see fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/z3tu0epb/

```
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.755690, -73.975938)
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nybb/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&geometryPrecision=8&outSR=4326&f=geojson');

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    alert("map is idle");
  });

}
```

I also know about the `addFeature()` listener which gets fired when any feature is added to the map, but I need the `alert()` to run after all the features are added to the map.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no feasible way to capture "after drawing all features" event for Data layer. It could be possible if the Data layer had exposed the instance of Drawing manager that is used internally. In this case you could listen to the `overlaycomplete` event

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayCompleteEvent

But the Data layer doesn't expose its Drawing manager instance publicly, so you cannot add a listener.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data

The unique thing that you can do is to figure out when all features were loaded (added to collection). In this case you can use a callback function of `loadGeoJson(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions, callback?:function(Array<Data.Feature>))`

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.755690, -73.975938)
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nybb/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&geometryPrecision=8&outSR=4326&f=geojson',
    {},
    function(features) {
        alert("Loaded " + features.length + " features");
    });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    alert("map is idle");
  });
  
  

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

Also, feel free to file a feature request for such event in the [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814)

Comment: Hi @xomena, I tested the function and is not working anymore. Did you find any alternative way?